# Terraform: provisioning via app/client id and secret

Tags: azure, terraform, devops, azure-rm

In azure portal, i have a registered app named 'terraform'.
I also created a Client Secret for this app.
Lastly, the App has the role 'Cloud  Application Administrator'

I would like to use this to run my terraform code which will create/provision resources.  i have the following:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.53.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      source = "azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "<subscription_id>"
  client_id = "<client_id>"
  client_secret = "<client_secret>"
  tenant_id = "<tenant_id>"
}
provider "azapi" {
  subscription_id = "<subscription_id>"
  client_id = "<client_id>"
  client_secret = "<client_secret>"
  tenant_id = "<tenant_id>"
  use_cli = true
}

data "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "container-registry"
  resource_group_name = "coreinfra-eastus-rg"
}
```

In the above, "container-registry" is an existing azure container registry.  when i run a `terraform plan`, i am seeing the following:

```
│ Error: retrieving Registry (Subscription: "<subscription_id>"
│ Resource Group Name: "coreinfra-eastus-rg"
│ Registry Name: "container-registry"): unexpected status 403 with error: AuthorizationFailed: The client '<object_id>' with object id '<object_id>' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/read' over scope '/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/coreinfra-eastus-rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/container-registry' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
│ 
│   with data.azurerm_container_registry.acr,
│   on data.tf line 1, in data "azurerm_container_registry" "acr":
│    1: data "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
```

In the above "<object_id>" is the id for my 'terraform' app.
How do i add the roles necessary to allow this app to broadly create/provision any cloud resources?
Is this the correct approach im taking - using an app to enable access to creation of cloud resources or is there a better approach?

Comment: Make sure to assign the **Reader** role at the Resource Group or Container Registry level to allow the Service Principal to retrieve the container registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/read'
```

> I also created a Client Secret for this app. Lastly, the App has the role 'Cloud Application Administrator'
>
> How do i add the roles necessary to allow this app to broadly create/provision any cloud resources?

The `Cloud Application Administrator`   is **Microsoft Entra ID** role for enabling, disable, and delete devices in `Microsoft Entra ID` in the `Azure portal`.

To `create or provision` resources within a subscription, you may need an **RBAC** role at the **subscription** level. In your case, as you are attempting to read the **container registry**, it may necessitate having the **Reader** Role on the `subscription` for the  `service principals`.

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.53.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      source = "azure/azapi"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "<subscription_id>"
  client_id = "<client_id>"
  client_secret = "<client_secret>"
  tenant_id = "<tenant_id>"
}
provider "azapi" {
  subscription_id = "<subscription_id>"
  client_id = "<client_id>"
  client_secret = "<client_secret>"
  tenant_id = "<tenant_id>"
  use_cli = true
}
data  "azurerm_container_registry"  "acr"  {
name = "venkatacrtest"
resource_group_name = "v-venkal-Mindtree"
}
```

After running the above **Terraform** code, I'm able to read the **container registry**.

[image]

Reference: [Cloud Device Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/permissions-reference#cloud-device-administrator)

[Assign Azure roles using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=delegate-condition)

Comment: thank you - can you explain how to add the RBAC role at the subscription level? i have to say that seems quite broad and dangerous.  But i will try it to confirm.
Btw, as any of this changed in the last 6 months - because all this was working fine about 6 months ago when i ran these scripts.

Comment: You may follow this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=delegate-condition for assigning RBAC role on subscription level.

Comment: This helped thanks.  i added the reader role, but i thinki need some 'List" roles:
```does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/listCredentials/action'```.   i dont see any such roles except for Kubernetes

Comment: Hi @mike01010, For the list credentials action, you can assign the Contributor role.